# Get user geolocated country name in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, geoip

I would like to add **"We ship to `{country name}`**" in WooCommerce header based on user geoip country name?

I would like to write html content in the header of my WooCommerce store, such as **We ship to "Your Country name"**.

Any help will be really appreciated?

I have WooCommerce geolocation enabled already.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make a custom function based on [`WC_Geolocation` Class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Geolocation.html) this way:

```
function get_user_geo_country(){
    $geo      = new WC_Geolocation(); // Get WC_Geolocation instance object
    $user_ip  = $geo->get_ip_address(); // Get user IP
    $user_geo = $geo->geolocate_ip( $user_ip ); // Get geolocated user data.
    $country  = $user_geo['country']; // Get the country code
    return WC()->countries->countries[ $country ]; // return the country name

}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE**

You will add the following code in your child theme's `header.php` file:

1) in between html code:

```
<?php printf( '<p>' . __('We ship to %s', 'woocommerce') . '</p>', get_user_geo_country() ); ?>
```

2) or in between php code:

```
printf( '<p>' . __('We ship to %s', 'woocommerce') . '</p>', get_user_geo_country() );
```

---

**Converting this to Shortcode:**

```
function get_user_geo_country(){
    $geo      = new WC_Geolocation(); // Get WC_Geolocation instance object
    $user_ip  = $geo->get_ip_address(); // Get user IP
    $user_geo = $geo->geolocate_ip( $user_ip ); // Get geolocated user data.
    $country  = $user_geo['country']; // Get the country code
    return sprintf( '<p>' . __('We ship to %s', 'woocommerce') . '</p>', WC()->countries->countries[ $country ] );
}
add_shortcode('geoip_country', 'get_user_geo_country');
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Normal shortcode usage *(in the backend text editor)*:

```
[geoip_country]
```

or in php code:

```
echo do_shortcode( "[geoip_country]" );
```

Comment: @loiceTheAztec, Thanks for your help, I tried it and i get this error " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in /home/fashi103/public_html/domainname.com/wp-content/themes/custheme-child/header-v4.php on line 79

Comment: i have removed the " <?php " and it work, can it be like this? or let me know how to close tag as it seem to close maybe.

Comment: thanks a lot Loic , Now i am trying to get this php code into my menu, do you have any idea how can i add it to the wordpress menu?

Comment: @Kristina Wordpress theming is not my strenght… so I don't know for now yet and it depend of your theme. Is possible to make a shortcode with it but it is not going to help you more...

Comment: I think i am gonna convert it to a shortcode which might be better. giving a try now. Thank You so much Loic. That was so sweet from you :)

Comment: @Kristina I have added the Shortcode version at the end (in case of need).

Comment: Loic is a Genius!